# pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-module, pyhook

i am trying to install the pyHook module on to my python. And i am getting an issue that says this:

```
pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Note that i am using python version 3.7. 
The way i tried to install it was by doing.

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

how would i be able to fix this
The reason why i want pyHook installed so bad is because i am watching a youtube video on how to create something using the pyHook module, so if it does not work, then the program wont work

Comment: What system you are working at? This whl is for 64bit windows system.

Comment: @w8eight i am running
```
16-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
```

Comment: ment 64 bit operating system, not 16